# spread exits directly after starting

Tags: configuration, integration, spread-toolkit

I just tried to start [spread](http://www.spreadconcepts.com/) for communication of some of my tools that I use in for the integration for different sensor data processes.

Just after the startup spread exits with the following message:

```
Conf_load_conf_file: using file: spread.conf
Successfully configured Segment 0 [127.0.0.255:4803] with 2 procs:
               localhost: 127.0.0.1
                   boron: 127.0.1.1
Finished configuration file.
Hash value for this configuration is: 913193717
Conf_load_conf_file: My proc id (129.70.129.5) is not in configuration
Exit caused by Alarm(EXIT)
```

As seen in the message I use the following spread.conf file to configure my local spread segment.

```
Spread_Segment 127.0.0.255:4803 {
 localhost 127.0.0.1
 boron 127.0.1.1
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the local machine I'm working at is not appearing in the config file according to spread. Spread tries to find the acutal IP 129.70.129.5 and not localhost in the .conf file. 
Changing my .conf file to:

```
Spread_Segment 127.0.0.255:4803 {
 localhost 127.0.0.1
 boron 129.70.129.5
}
```

or starting spread with

```
spread -n localhost
```

does the trick.