# can i run two process that use spread on the same machine without them see each other?

Tags: cluster-computing, spread, spread-toolkit

I have two process that use spread-toolkit and i want to run them on the same machine but the are not suppose to see each other in the spread.

The only simple solution that I can come up with is running to spread instances on different ports and configuration on the same machine.

Is there any way to separate them in the spread configuration instead of the solution above?

Comment: I have updated my answer with some spread-specific configuration information that may help you.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Spread specific answer**

According to the [FAQ](http://www.spread.org/faq.html):

> **Configuration and Setup Questions**
>
> ```
> What ports can you run it on?
>
> Any ports you want. Just change the ports in the configuration file spread.conf
> and restart the Spread daemons. We recommend using random high ports over 2000.
> ```

If you're on a linux or similar platform, the configuration is in /etc/spread.conf.  If you're on a Windows platform, you'll need to poke around to find it.

You can set up multiple spread segments on different ports.  See pages 9-12 of the [user guide](http://www.spread.org/docs/guide/users_guide.pdf).  In addition, you may find a scrap or two of information in this Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922102/spread-exits-directly-after-starting).  Here's a quick example fragment:

```
Spread_Segment 192.168.0.255:2000 {
 machine1 192.168.0.1
 machine1 192.168.0.2
}

Spread_Segment 192.168.0.255:2001 {
 machine1 192.168.0.1
 machine1 192.168.0.2
}
```

Caveat: I have merely updated my answer with some readily available information that I hope will be helpful.  I do not carry practical experience in using Spread at this time.

**Original Answer**

There may be a solution specific to [the spread toolkit](http://www.spread.org/), however, not being familiar with it, I will mention some more general methods you might use.

If your cluster is running linux, you can probably do what you want by using [Linux Containers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC).  These are based on a kernel feature called [control groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups).

If your cluster is running a BSD derivative, the corresponding technology are [BSD Jails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail).  BSD Jails have been in existance longer than the linux option, and is very well tested.

Both of these methods use operating system virtualisation, which is much lighter (less overhead) than both full- and para-virtualisation.